# Problem using the table tag

Tags: css, xhtml

I am trying to use the table tag to contruct a section of my site. Basically, I want a three column table with each column separated from each other and having a styled border round it (e.g 1px solid #000000).

I understand each table column cannot be separated with margins using CSS so i used border-spacing and border-collapse property as follows.

```
border-collapse:separate;
border-spacing:10px 50px;
```

The above partically worked in that the columns got separated however, i was unable to have a surrounding border on each column.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to put the border on individual td elements.  It's awkward because that means you have to put top and bottom borders on td's in top and bottom rows.  Scott may be right that you want to use div's instead, but then again for all we know it is tabular data you are displaying, and you just want it styled a particular way.

edit:
Here, this seems to do what you want, if a tad kludgy, and with the caveat that on early versions of IE, firstChild and lastChild only work with the right DOCTYPE:

```
table { border-collapse: separate;  border-spacing:  2px 0; }

td { border: solid black;  border-width: 0px 1px;}

tr:first-child td {
border-top-width: 1px;
}

tr:last-child td {
border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's truly tabular data though since the OP wants to highlight on a column basis.

Comment: @Scott, maybe not, but but maybe it is.  Is there some reason tabular data shouldn't be displayed with borders around the columns?  Maybe that wouldn't be your choice, but it is a cosmetic question and I think is up to gables20 to make that decision.

Comment: This is not a judgement of his decision; it's just a statement that using divs for the columns gives you more options since the desired display is columnar, not tabular.  No hate! :)

Comment: @Scott:  assuming he has multiple rows, and those rows need to adjust their vertical size based on the content, as well as to stay aligned vertically, divs wouldn't really do the job.  Note that some of the tables on this page http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/ effectively have borders around rows (although not in quite the same way gables20 seems to want them).

Comment: @rob, thanks i've tried it out however, do you mind stating what the right doctype is because at the moment, i am using strict.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better served providing a link to the page with the data/content you want structured. As I stated earlier in this post, I'm of a mind to think that nested divs would serve you well. This is turning into a 'discussion' rather than an 'answer.'

Answer (score 0):

You might consider reading up on the `<div>` tag; using tables for layout is frowned upon these days.

Comment: Thanks scott for your response, i am quite aware of that, and stay away from tables myself, however, i would still like to know if what i am asking is possible....?

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Scott. Tables are for data. Divs are for formatting. You'll likely also have to do some homework on Cascading Style Sheets if you're not familiar with them.

Comment: Thanks for you response, i am quite familiar with css and am pretty sure i would be able to achieve what i want with divs, however, i want to know out of curiousity if what i am asking is possible?

Comment: It is a reasonable question and there is no way in the world we can know whether it is tabular data or not, based on his cosmetic choice for how it is displayed.

Comment: Which is why a link to the issue would be of import. I'm of a mind to think that nested divs would do the trick, but not knowing the structure of the data in question, it's all conjecture.